# Displaying multiple results with same id in a table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an audit database that has two tables, one displaying the audit information and the other has all of the audits findings. When an audit is entered the auditor, area, date and score are entered into the results table which assigns an ID # to it. The other table has three columns, one for the primary key, the ID# from the results table and a column for the findings, which can be up to 19 individual rows per audit.

What I am trying to do is make a script that searches the results table by auditor and joins all of the results with the findings from the audits finding table. The issue that I am having is grouping the audits by id number. Right now it is displaying the individual rows but I would like for it to display the info from the results table (name, area, date...) and then have all of the findings for that specific audit listed beneath it. I've tried adding a CONCAT into the query but it only displays the first finding.

Here's what I have so far.

```
   $data=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT results.auditor, results.area, results.esp_unit, results.score, results.date, findings.Finding
               FROM audits.results
               INNER JOIN audits.findings
               ON results.id=findings.id
               WHERE auditor='$_POST[Auditor]' AND time < Now()
               GROUP BY results.date")
                 or die(mysqli_error());



                 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

                 while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $data ))
                    {
                         Print "<table border cellpadding=3>";

                         Print "<tr BGCOLOR='#dcf6f7'>";
                         Print "<th>Auditor:</th> <td>".$info['auditor'] . "</td> ";
                         Print "</tr>";
                         Print "<tr>"
                         Print "<th>ESP Unit:</th> <td>".$info['esp_unit'] . " </td>";
                         Print "</tr>";
                         Print "<tr>"
                         Print "<th>Area:</th><td>".$info['area'] . "</td>";
                         Print "</tr>";
                         Print "<tr>"
                         Print "<th>Score:</th><td>".$info['score'] ."</td>";
                         Print "</tr>";
                         Print "<tr>"
                         Print "<th>Date:</th><td>".$info['date']  ."</td>";
                         Print "</tr>";
                         Print "<tr>";
                         Print "<th>Finding:</th><td>".$info['Finding']  ."</td>";
                            Print "</tr>";
                             }
                   Print "</table>";

                mysqli_close($con);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Order the results by ID. Then have your printing loop check whether the current row's ID is the same as the previous row's, and skip showing the duplicate result data -- just show the findings data.